# How to render nested ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have such nested `ng-template` structure.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <list>
      <ng-template *ngFor="let item of Items" #ListItem>
        <ng-template #ListItemLine>{{ item[0] }}</ng-template>
        <ng-template #ListItemLine>{{ item[1] }}</ng-template>
        <ng-template #ListItemLine>{{ item[2] }}</ng-template>
        I can see this line, but can't get above templates
      </ng-template>
    </list>
  `,
})
export class App {
  Items: Array<Array<string>> = [
    [ "1-1", "1-2", "1-3", ],
    [ "2-1", "2-2", "2-3", ],
    [ "3-1", "3-2", "3-3", ],
    [ "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", ],
    [ "5-1", "5-2", "5-3", ],
  ]
}
```

How can I render children `ng-component` in my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of Items">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item"></ng-container>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class ListComponent {

  @ContentChildren('ListItem') public Items;

}
```

Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Hi1ZqPAAYyIbclUuzRrl?p=preview

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

At the end I want to wrap Angular Material components into my components, so if I would find a btter UI than Material, I shouldn't have to change all accurances of Material components in my program, I would just need to change implementation of my wrapper UI components.

For exmple let's try to wrap `mat-list` component. I need to make a wrapper for `mat-list` container, let's call it `my-list`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
    <mat-list>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-list>
  `,
})
```

and a wrapper for `mat-list-item`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list-item',
  template: `
    <mat-list-item>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-list>
  `,
})
```

The HTML render result would be:

- my-list

  - mat-list

    - my-list-item

      - mat-list-item
    - ...

Each Material component surrounded by my wrapper, so directives and styles which come with Material will not work.

Comment: I don't think you really need the nested template. Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Only the parent template gets rendered in your code because you only select the parent templates. The    @ContentChildren('ListItem') only selects the top level templates so only that ones are rendered. To render also the child templates you have to do something with them. Maybe you should just use a normal *ngfor to expand also the nested objects inside the parent template and avoid the nested templates.

Comment: @AlesD `ng-template` gives me oportunity to render it's content without wrapper element, so nested structure of `ng-template` should give me opportunity to render a tree of elements without wrappers. At the end I want to incapsulate Material list component inside my component, and be able to use directives like `matLine` which doesn't work if it wrapped.

Comment: @AlesD Yes I know that I don't render them, because I don't know how to reference them.

Comment: If you want to reference them from inside another template you need to do this in code I still think there is a better solution from what you want to do. If you want to build a recursive tree structure you can build recursive component.

Comment: Here is a plunk of how to render all from your template. This is also more efficient because you do not create new sub templates for every parent template rendering. [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/zbTnViNZex6d88qu7363?p=preview)

Comment: @AlesD Please check my Update.

Comment: Ok thanks this is now more clear. Will make a solution and post it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would solve this based on the information you provided. As you already suggested I have made two components `list` and `list-item`.
The list component renders the `list-item` components based on an input array and the content of the list component must contain a template that defines the list item template. Sample code:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'list',
      template: `
        <ul>
          <list-item *ngFor="let item of items" [data]="item" [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"></list-item>
          <ng-content></ng-content>
        </ul>
      `,
    })
    export class ListComponent {
      @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
      public itemTemplate: TemplateRef;
      @Input()
      public items: any[];

    }
```

Then the `list-item` component just renders the list item template provided in the a container element. Sample code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list-item',
  template: `
      <li>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; itemContext"></ng-container>
      </li>
  `,
})
export class ListItemComponent {
  @Input()
  public data: any;
  @Input()
  public itemTemplate: Template;
  public get itemContext(): any {
    return { $implicit: data };
  }
}
```

You can then use it in different ways. I made an example just a simple list and another where the item template is again a list so you get a list of lists simmilar to a tree. Sample code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <list [items]="Items">
      <ng-template let-items>{{ items | json }}</ng-template>
    </list>
    <list [items]="Items">
      <ng-template let-items>
        <list [items]="items">
          <ng-template let-items>{{ items | json }}</ng-template>
        </list>
      </ng-template>
    </list>
  `,
})
export class App {
  Items: Array<Array<string>> = [
    [ "1-1", "1-2", "1-3", ],
    [ "2-1", "2-2", "2-3", ],
    [ "3-1", "3-2", "3-3", ],
    [ "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", ],
    [ "5-1", "5-2", "5-3", ],
  ]
}
```

I made also a plunker sample with the code where you can run it. [Plunker Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/zbTnViNZex6d88qu7363?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not what I expected. It looks like `ng-template` and `ng-container` possibilities is not enough for my purpose. Your example passing data over inputs and I expect all data to be passed over content. Anyhow your example very helpful. I will do some workaround and maybe later will do some custom templates.